# Matlab FFT Peak at 0 Hz without Offset

Tags: matlab, fft

i've got a dataset with lenght 2048. This represents 1 second. There are 2048 entries in the dataset ranging from -200 to +400. I want to see what frequencies are in there.
[z_off i want this to FFT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOMFk.png)

z_off is 1x2048 double

How can I get rid of the peak at 0 Hz?
Also FFT doesnt seem to work...

```
z_off = z-mean(z);

plot(abs(fft(z_off)));
y = fft(z_off);     
f = (0:length(y)-1)*2048/length(y);

plot(f,abs(y))
title('Magnitude')
```

can you help me please?

Comment: Please, read why  a [mcve] is required to get help. Also, why do you want to remove a peak? That is the result

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the fft does not work? Please describe what you are seeing as a result and what you would expect to see.

Comment: There is always a peak at 0Hz. This is the static amplitude (it is in fact the same as the arithmetic average of your signal)

Comment: I run your code snippet with `z = rand(1, 2048);` and I get y(1) = 1.4992e-12, which is effectively 0 at 0 Hz. You shouldn't be getting a peak in the 0 frequency mode.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a peak at 0 Hz, then it is just telling you that your signal is not stationary, i.e. that it is trending up or down. Is this expected?

The fft is telling you that there is energy in those low frequencies. Another way of saying this is that as the frequency gets low (or the wavelength gets long), you signal is still bouncing around.

You will need to do some filtering (high-pass) to remove this, if that is what you really want to do.

Comment: The 0 frequency is the mean of the signal, has nothing to do with it being stationary or not. A 0-mean signal has no amplitude at 0 Hz.